# PHP Concatenates Adding Space Variables

Tags: php

I have to display all three variables, while adding a space between each one and assigns the result of the concatenation into a 4th variable named $result.

I can't figure out how to put a space between the different variables.

```
<?php

$a = "xCx";
$b = "xAx";
$c = "zAz"; 

$result = $a.$b.$c;

echo $result;
```

I have xCxxAxzAz. Need xCx xAx zAz

Comment: um........... so add some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then concatenate the spaces...

```
$a . ' ' . $b . ' ' .$c;
```

Comment: Gracias @Funk, the iPad does weird quotes.

Comment: De nada Jay; I figured as much ;-)